# install icons on sublime 3 sidebar with seti ui icons

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to install icons for sublime 3 with this [repo](https://github.com/mrmartineau/SetiUI-Icons-Sublime). At step 4 it says:

> If your theme is Soda Dark 3, then create a new file called "Soda Dark
>   3" in the newly downloaded directory.

What file am I making? What is the file type? Is it .sublime-package? My theme is `TwoDark` but where do I get the name I need for the file?

Answer (score 0):

In the example the filename should be "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme", works for me.